# Adding more constrain in sentry 2 authentication processs

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Do you have any ideas, how to add some more constrain while authentication in sentry 2, I have a company table and users belongs to a company, and if the company is disabled(set the active to 0 to mark it as disabled in the company table) then the user should not be able to login.

In short while logging some users it should check for the company they belongs to and check if it is active or not, if not then do not log them in or throw an exception.

...Please help if u have any idea about it. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to pass the company field to Sentry::authenticate()?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep it simple without changing the sentry 2 code.

```
try
{
    $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
    if ($user->company->active == 0)
    {
        Sentry::logout();
        // Redirect to login page with the proper flash message
    }
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e)
{
}
... other catches
```

**Update**
If you want, you can create your own service provider for Sentry2. When registering classes, you can register a class that extends the \Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry class and override the `login()` method.

Your code will looks like the following:

```
public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
{
    if ( ! $user->isActivated())
    {
        $login = $user->getLogin();
        throw new UserNotActivatedException("Cannot login user [$login] as they are not activated.");
    }

    // you can create this method in your company model
    if ($user->company->isDisabled()) 
    {
        throw new CompanyDisabledException("... message ...");
    }


    $this->user = $user;

    // Create an array of data to persist to the session and / or cookie
    $toPersist = array($user->getId(), $user->getPersistCode());

    // Set sessions
    $this->session->put($toPersist);

    if ($remember)
    {
        $this->cookie->forever($toPersist);
    }

    // The user model can attach any handlers
    // to the "recordLogin" event.
    $user->recordLogin();
}
```

Comment: hmm...i thought the same, but sentry sets the last_login field in the users table....how to overcome that ??
Any more ideas, Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can save the company/active or not status on the `Users` table and later on your login controller, you can pass to the `$credentials` array the additional fields you want to check on the process.

Something like this must do the job:

```
// Set login credentials
$credentials = array(
    'email'    => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'company'  => 1,
);

// Authenticate user
Sentry::authenticate($credentials, Input::get('remember-me', 0));
```